# socat multiple connections -- sequentially

Tags: linux, networking

I'm using `socat` on a linux system that is connected to two physically separate, private networks so that TightVNC clients on one network can access TightVNC servers on the other network. Right now, `socat` allows one connection and then terminates, as expected.

I'm having trouble with the documentation/description for "multiple connections" because I cannot determine if what I see allows more then one connection at the same time (i.e. BAD [for me]) or multiple connections, one after another without terminating and restarting the program (i.e. what I want).

I hope I've described my confusion well enough for an expert here to help me out. I haven't been able to come up with a google search query that gets me anything except documents with phrases like, "...to allow multiple connections with socat..." but they never seem to say which of the two multiple connection "modes" they're talking about.

If it is of any use, here's one of my commands (which are all the same except for the ports and addresses):

`sudo -b socat TCP-LISTEN:5900 TCP:192.168.1.10:5900`

If `socat` cannot do this itself, is there a linux program that I can wrap around `socat` to restart it any time it exits?

My current work-around is to use this shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
(while true; do
   sudo socat TCP4-LISTEN:5901 TCP4:192.168.1.2:5900
done) &
```

This works but can be tricky to *stop* when I'm done with it.  I'm hoping that `socat` can be instructed to [effectively] start *itself* over after the incoming connection is closed.

Oh, I was referred here from Stack Overflow's Network Engineering site because they don't answer this kind of question.

Comment: normally you'd use the ,fork option to allow any number of connections at the same time. Why do you only want them sequentially?

Comment: It is for remote control of a workstation, so multiple, simultaneous users would be a problem and therefore should not be allowed.

Comment: "but can be tricky to stop when I'm done with it" – Related: [*Proper handling of SIGINT/SIGQUIT*](https://www.cons.org/cracauer/sigint.html). It seems `socat` in my Kubuntu 23.04 does *not* handle SIGINT properly; probably neither does yours. Too bad. I guess we can consider this a bug in `socat`. If it behaved like my `sleep`, there would be no problem. I mean `while date; do sleep 1; done` can easily be terminated by Ctrl+c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to combine Socats fork option with the max-children option:

```
sudo -b socat TCP-LISTEN:5900,fork,max-children=1 TCP:192.168.1.10:5900
```

It will continue to accept connections only when there are less then 1 children active.

Comment: Thanks!  I think this is exactly what I was looking for and I'm kinda shamed I didn't come up with it on my own.